# Confusion regarding simulink?

Tags: simulink, simulink-library

I was looking at simulink library browser and i noticed something that i am unable to understand.
I have attached a snapshot and encircled red and highlighted yellow certain items.

As you can see in attached snap, the top and first blue and yellow highlighted item **simulink** is also available in Library browser. why it is named like that?

And other categories encircled in red boundary for example aerospace blockset and communication blockset are not under category/heading of simulink. why?  **Are they not part of main simulink? are they add ons or additional components of simulink?**
[image]

Comment: The items circled in red are not part of the standard Simulink installation, they come with additional toolboxes that are purchased separately from Simulink.

Answer (score 0):

All of the additional Simulink library blocksets and toolboxes below the "Simulink"
category require additional licenses. Use the command `license('inuse')` to see which licenses you are currently using. If a license is unavailable (e.g. you're sharing them on a network, and they are all in use) then you will not be able to run any models that use those blocks.